# Angular FormArray content updated after push/removeAt using OnPush

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, formarray

I have a component which is using `OnPush` change detection.
In this component I have a `FormArray` (inside of a `FormGroup`).
I have two buttons, which add(`push`) or remove(`removeAt`) `FormGroup` in `FormArray`.
I expect because of the `OnPush` change detection the changes are not visible (there is no change in the root `FormGroup` reference)
However the component is detecting the changes perfectly.

I find a similar example ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fthings%2Fthings.component.ts)) where the changeDetection called manually, but when I remove that part of the code, it is still working fine.

I checked the [Angular source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1866) and my guess is that the `updateValueAndValidity` function call is doing the change detection, also this [StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687560/angular-2-forms-onpush/61009067#61009067) confirms it.

So can somebody explain how it is working exactly?
I wouldn't like to break my application in the future after an Angular update.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Even with `OnPush` strategy Angular automatically checks for changes in a component when an event handler in the component fires (like click event handler in your case). If you call `removeAt` or `push` not inside a click handler, but for instance in `setTimeout`, changes won't be visible.